# По нажатию на кнопку записать квадрат введенного числа. Не могу понять почему код не рабочий

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Даны два инпута и кнопка. В первый пользователь вводит число. По нажатию на кнопку запишите во второй инпут квадрат введенного числа.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 </head>
  <body>
 <input type="text" id="text1" value="Введите число">
 <input type="text" id="text2" value="Здесь появится результат">
  <input type="button" id="but" value="Нажми на меня">
   <script type="text/javascript">
   text1.addEventListener("focus", function(){this.value = null}, false);
    but.addEventListener("click", function(){
        if (isNaN(parseInt(text1.value))) {alert("Введено не число")}
        else{ text2.value = Math.pow(parseInt(text1.value ),2);
        text1.value = null;
        } ,false);
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: если это js то поставьте соответствующую метку. И напишите конкретно что значит "не рабочий"

Comment: Код рабочий, только закрывающей скобки у обработчика не хватает.

Comment: неплохо было бы инициализировать ваши text1 и but каким то значнеим, например, ссылкой на  соответствующий узел DOM

Comment: А где именно я скобку потеряла ?

Answer (score 0):

А вы смотрите в консоль на ошибки или нет?
Вы не закрыли все скобки и код ругался на код.
Что-бы смотреть в консоль нажмите `F12` и выберете `Console`, там будут выводиться ошибки и данные если вы бедете использовать `console.log([значение])`;

```js
text1.addEventListener("focus", function() {
  this.value = null;
}, false);

but.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (isNaN(parseInt(text1.value))) {
    alert("Введено не число");
  } else {
    text2.value = Math.pow(parseInt(text1.value), 2);
    text1.value = null;
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" id="text1" value="Введите число">
  <input type="text" id="text2" value="Здесь появится результат">
  <input type="button" id="but" value="Нажми на меня">
</body>
```